# execute-api with Cognito federated identities from Cognito user pools

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, federated-identity, amazon-javascript-sdk

I want to execute APIs hosted on AWS API gateway using identity I created from Cognito federated identities with Cognito user pool as provider. Basically option 2   in this blog here [Secure API Access with Amazon Cognito Federated Identities, Amazon Cognito User Pools, and Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/secure-api-access-with-amazon-cognito-federated-identities-amazon-cognito-user-pools-and-amazon-api-gateway/)

Now I have the federated identity credentials but stuck on how to actually execute the API. There does not seem to be such an API in the AWS JS SDK for API gateway. Does that mean the only way to do this is to create the SigV4 myself & call it like any other HTTP API?

Any suggestions/easier solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, did this use AWS sign web library from  https://github.com/danieljoos/aws-sign-web. It does the job.